# AdWords API, getRefreshToken url not working

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to get the refresh access token from AdWords API but the url generated by GetRefreshToken does not really work despite the fact I am logged in with the user that owns and created the API token.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people who also get stuck in the new oAUTH2 auth. of AdWords, here's the solution.
In the google code console, when you create your project, in the consent screen you must fill in all the fields required for WEB application. This is because the url you hit provided by the php script requires web access permissions and if not provided you get a bunch of weird unrelated errors.

Hope this helps.